# Generating a group.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose we want to show that the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is generated by $s$ and $sr$. 
Once we've generated an element, can we go on to use that element to generate the other elements in the group or must we only use $sr$ and $r$ explicitly.

In other words is the following proof valid:

$s(sr)=r \Rightarrow  r^{k}=(r)(r)(r)...(r)$ and so we've generated all elements of the from $r^{k}$ where $1\leq k\leq n-1$.

And since all elements of the form $sr^{k}$ can be generated from $r$ and $sr$ we are done.

Comment: Yes you can do this. If $s(sr) = r$, then $r^k = s(sr)s(sr)\cdots s(sr)$ $k$ times. In exactly the same way, when I write $2+3$ I don't write out $(1+1)+(1+1+1)$. It's fine to use the fact that $2 = 1+1$, $3=1+1+1$ and to work from there.

Comment: Thanks. I thought so too, but wasn't completely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use elements that you constructed to construct further elements, as you could always substitute the original expression. Formally one could state it like this:

*Lemma:* Let $S \subset G$ be a subset of a group, and let $s \in \langle S \rangle$ the subgroup generated by $S$. Then $\langle S \cup \{s\} \rangle = \langle S \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks. Just needed to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

$$ r^2 = r*r = s(sr)*s(sr) = (s)(sr)(s)(sr)$$ for example and the general case follows exactly. So yes, once you have written a specific element in terms of your proposed generators, you may freely use that element to help you generate others. The reasoning in general is analogous to the one proposed above.